# Nginx Rewrite For Magento/Fishpig integration

Tags: wordpress, magento, nginx

I have Magento and Wordpress running together via Fishpig integration. Which is fine.

Fishpig requires to use a prefix in your URL to identify it's WP related (e.g. http:/domain.com/blog/your-page-url).

What I need is a Nginx rewrite for URLs which won't have the blog bit.

If I user types

```
http:/domain.com/your-page-url or 
http:/domain.com/another-page-url?somevar=1
```

I want to keep the URL like that but internally Nginx would deliver

```
http:/domain.com/blog/your-page-url
http:/domain.com/blog/another-page-url?somevar=1
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the `/blog` prefix, how can `nginx` differentiate between Magento and WordPress? It needs to decide which service to send the request to. I think that your proposal would break Magento.

Comment: Hey @RichardSmith, thanks for your input. That's the thing, What I'm trying above is not break Magento. If I catch those URL at the top via NGINX, add the /blog and deliver them internally to to magento with the slug it could work. Does it make sense?